# How to set div tag height and width using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, height, width

How can I set the width and height of a `div` using JavaScript?

Here is my code

```
<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>View JSON</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var rect1='{"minX": 0.0,"minY": 0.0,"maxX": 2460.0,"maxY": 3008.0}';
var rectangle = JSON.parse(rect1);
var maxx=rectangle.maxX;
var maxy=rectangle.maxY;

***What should i do here?***

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h5>JSON View</h5>
<div id="set">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to set the div width to `maxx` and height to `maxy` values. I also want to set its border to `1px` so that I can see whether it's working or not.

Thanks

Comment: What is the point of parsing it as JSON from a string like that? Why not just make an object literal? JSON stands for javascript object notation anyhow. Also, you'll want to put that script at the bottom of  the DOM to ensure the elements you wish to manipulate get parsed and loaded first.

Comment: Simply do `document.getElementById("set").style.height = maxy+"px"` and similarly for width do `document.getElementById("set").style.width = maxx+"px"`. For border do `document.getElementById("set").style.border = "solid 1px black"`

Comment: You can find this on google in less time than you spent posting this question :-)

Comment: @Gatekeeper what do you think i didnt search in google?

Comment: @Shiju K Babu well if I put "set div width javascript" into google, first few pages shows me how to do it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use

```
document.getElementById('set').style.width = maxX + "px";
```

and

```
document.getElementById('set').style.height = maxY + "px";
```

Also, you may need to make sure the document is loaded before the script runs, or else the set div may not have been created. You do this in window.onload as foillows:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
  Javascript code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd make use of the element's `style`:

```
document.getElementById('set').style.width = maxx + "px";
document.getElementById('set').style.height = maxy + "px";
document.getElementById('set').style.border = "1px solid #000";
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/X5k2Q/).

Being a fixed value, border in this case would probably be better controlled with just CSS.

```
div#set {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```